# How to speed up custom function

Tags: python, pandas, function

How to speed up my custom function?

I have three list of numbers :

list1
list2
list3

And Pandas Dataframe like this:

| id | inum | DESC_1 | recs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | inum1 | 1 | recs1 |
| id2 | inum2 | 2 | recs2 |
| id3 | inum3 | 3 | recs3 |

And my custom function:

```
def keep_inum(row):
    if len(row) != 0:
        if int(row['inum']) in list1:
            if row['DESC_1'] == 1:
                return row['recs']
            else:
                return ''
        elif int(row['inum']) in list2:
            if row['DESC_1'] == 2:
                return row['recs']
            else:
                return ''
        elif int(row['inum']) in list3:
            if row['DESC_1'] == 3:
                return row['recs']
            else:
                return ''
        else:
            return row['recs']
    else:
        pass
```

Apply func to DF:

```
df['recs'] = df.apply(keep_inum, axis = 1)
```

Comment: don't you get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'inum1'` for the expression `int(row['inum'])` ?

Comment: No, I don't get. Here row['inum'] is str like '123456'

Comment: so those values `12345` should have been in your input instead of vague `"inum"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using a custom function at all:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"],
        "inum": ["111", "222", "333", "331"],
        "DESC_1": [1, 4, 3, 3],
        "recs": ["recs1", "recs2", "recs3", "yes"],
    }
)

print(df)
print("---")

list1 = [111]
list2 = [222]
list3 = [333, 331]

# Cast inum to int in one go
df["inum_int"] = df["inum"].astype(int)
# Empty the recs where inum doesn't match desc
df.loc[df["inum_int"].isin(list1) & ~(df["DESC_1"] == 1), "recs"] = ""
df.loc[df["inum_int"].isin(list2) & ~(df["DESC_1"] == 2), "recs"] = ""
df.loc[df["inum_int"].isin(list3) & ~(df["DESC_1"] == 3), "recs"] = ""
df.drop(columns=["inum_int"], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

This outputs

```
    id inum  DESC_1   recs
0  id1  111       1  recs1
1  id2  222       4  recs2
2  id3  333       3  recs3
3  id4  331       3    yes
---
    id inum  DESC_1   recs
0  id1  111       1  recs1
1  id2  222       4       
2  id3  333       3  recs3
3  id4  331       3    yes
```

Comment: Is it calculating row-by row in DF?

Comment: and got TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

Comment: @AntonKurtis Yes and no – it's using a mask to make Pandas do the hard work internally. Secondly, fixed the unhashable type issue, forgot to use `.loc`.

Comment: In that case, ["new_recs"] and ["recs"] then are empty.

Comment: Well, I don't know about your data, but if you run the above, it certainly works.

Comment: Yeah, It's work fine, thank you!!! Just my custom func return  ["recs"] if ["new_recs"] is empty.

Or df["inum_int"].isin(list2) & (df["DESC_1"] == 2) is False, I need return  ["recs"] to  ["new_recs"]

Comment: Oh... well, actually that simplifies things. Just a sec.

Comment: @AntonKurtis Right, I revised the code to work on `recs` in-place since it looks like you really just want to clear the `recs` column where there is a mismatch between the list and the desc column?

Comment: Yeah, done it!
Like 
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('', pd.NA).fillna(df['B']). Now it fast. Thanks alot!